# Route to remove action from URL in CakePHP 3 not working

Tags: cakephp, routes, action

In my routes.php file, I've put this into Router::scope('/', function ($routes) {

$routes->connect(
    '/:controller/:id',
    ['action' => 'view'],
    ['id' => '[0-9]+']
);

However it does not seem to work? The URLs still go to players/view/1

I'm not sure what I'm doing wrong

Answer (score 0):

From the book: [book.cakephp.org/3.0/en/development/routing.html#route-elements](http://book.cakephp.org/3.0/en/development/routing.html#route-elements) (just below the code you may have cut-and-pasted):

> CakePHP does not automatically produce lowercased and dashed URLs when using the :controller parameter. If you need this, the above example could be rewritten like so:

`$routes->connect(
    '/:controller/:id',
    ['action' => 'view'],
    ['id' => '[0-9]+', 'routeClass' => 'DashedRoute']
);`

...and then a little further down:

> Once this route has been defined, requesting `/apples/5` would call the `view()` method of the ApplesController. Inside the `view()` method, you would need to access the passed ID at `$this->request->params['id']`.

So in my (for example) ApplesController's `view()` method, I added the following at the very top:

`if ($id == null) {
    $id = $this->request->params['id'];
}`

...and now `apples/view/5` and `apples/5` both work the same way.